# How to get all record related parent and child in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
NoteID(PK)  NoteText    ParentNoteID
1           x           -  
2           y           1
3           z           -
4           a           2
5           b           -
6           z           4
```

How to get all record relating key

ex. get NiteID **4** than result should be 1,2.4,6 all id or all object filter.

Comment: have you tried anything? please give your code here.

Comment: I have not tried to Django, currently, I m trying on DB(MySQL) level, but finally, I want to do through Django.

Comment: select  identifier_id,
        link_identifier_id 
from    (select identifier_id,link_identifier_id from NRS_IDENTIFIER  
         order by link_identifier_id, identifier_id) a  ,
        (select @pv := '979') b
where   find_in_set(link_identifier_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', identifier_id));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be your model class

```
class Note(models.Model):
   note_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Then the function can be like this:

```py
def recursive(note, child_list): 
    note_children = Note.objects.filter(parent=note) 
    child_list.append(note.id) 
    if note_children.count()==0: 
         return child_list 
    for n in note_children: 
        recursive(n, child_list)  

    return child_list
```